# subtracting consecutive values in R

Tags: r, formula

Basically I have a data like this:

```
Begin.Time..s.  1.039*** 3.133* 5.156 7.168 9.249 11.362             

End.Time..s.  1.383**  3.437  5.5  7.539 9.546 11.674
```

I would like to make the following operation:

```
3.133* - (1.383** - 1.039***)
```

And then continue until the end of the data.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @P9710053 Is 3.133* constant for all calculation

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lag` function from `dplyr`, we can do the following,

```
df$Begin[-1] - na.omit(dplyr::lag(df$End - df$Begin))
#[1]  2.789  4.852  6.824  8.878 11.065
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Begin = c(1.039, 3.133, 5.156, 7.168, 9.249, 11.362
), End = c(1.383, 3.437, 5.5, 7.539, 9.546, 11.674)), .Names = c("Begin", 
"End"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT**
Based on @nicola's suggestion, a lighter approach would be

```
df1$Begin[-1]-(df1$End-df1$Begin)[-nrow(df1)]
#[1]  2.789  4.852  6.824  8.878 11.065
```

Comment: Invoking `dplyr` and calling `na.omit` seems a little to much for this simple task. `df$Begin[-1]-(df$End-df$Begin)[-nrow(df)]` is enough.

Comment: True. I was going to use base functions to create the lagged var but with `dplyr`'s `lag` it becomes very readable.

Answer (score 0):

hope it may be useful from base R

```
df1$Begin[2:length(df1$Begin)]-(df1$End[1:5]-df1$Begin[1:5])
[1]  2.789  4.852  6.824  8.878 11.065
```

## data

copied from previous OP sotos